# Parsing selections from a fixed list in Boost.Spirit

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

Starting from the [Employee - Parsing into structs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/employee___parsing_into_structs.html) example:

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct employee_parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, employee(), ascii::space_type>
{
    employee_parser() : employee_parser::base_type(start)
    {
        using qi::int_;
        using qi::lit;
        using qi::double_;
        using qi::lexeme;
        using ascii::char_;

        quoted_string %= lexeme['"' >> +(char_ - '"') >> '"'];

        start %=
            lit("employee")
            >> '{'
            >>  int_ >> ','
            >>  quoted_string >> ','
            >>  quoted_string >> ','
            >>  double_
            >>  '}'
            ;
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type> quoted_string;
    qi::rule<Iterator, employee(), ascii::space_type> start;
};
```

suppose I wanted to replace `quoted_string` with a rule that matches any string stored in a given container.

For example, if I have a container such as:

```
std::array<std::string, 4> match_list =
   { "string0", "string1", "string2", "string3" };
```

and I want the parser to only match the input against one of the values in the array (the container doesn't have to be an array).

I'm sure this is simple, but the Spirit help pages don't seem to address this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/string/symbols.html

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f4bde2004610598)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct employee {
    int id;
    std::string sym;
    std::string name;
    double value;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(employee, id, sym, name, value) 

template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
struct employee_parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, employee(), Skipper>
{
    employee_parser() : employee_parser::base_type(start)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        quoted_string = lexeme['"' >> +(char_ - '"') >> '"'];

        symbol_.add
            ("string0")
            ("string1")
            ("string2")
            ("string3")
            ;

        start =
            lit("employee")
            >> '{'
            >>  int_ >> ','
            >>  symbol_ >> ','
            >>  quoted_string >> ','
            >>  double_
            >>  '}'
            ;
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), Skipper> quoted_string;
    qi::rule<Iterator, employee(), Skipper> start;
    qi::symbols<char, std::string> symbol_;
};

int main() {
    std::string const input = "employee { 42, string3, \"more names or stuff\", 6.7 }";

    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    It f = input.begin(), l = input.end();

    employee_parser<It> p;

    employee e;
    if (phrase_parse(f, l, p, qi::space, e)) {
        using boost::fusion::operator<<;
        std::cout << boost::fusion::tuple_delimiter(';');
        std::cout << "Parsed: " << e << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Remaining input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed: (42;;more names or stuff;6.7)
```

To actually include values:

```
    symbol_.add
        ("string0", "STRING0")
        ("string1", "STRING1")
        ("string2", "STRING2")
        ("string3", "STRING3")
        ;
```

Prints **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7428565075349d0a)</kbd>**

```
Parsed: (42;STRING3;more names or stuff;6.7)
```

Or you can use another type altogether:

```
    symbol_.add
        ("string0", 0)
        ("string1", 1)
        ("string2", 2)
        ("string3", 3)
        ;
```

With

```
    symbol_.add
        ("string0", 0)
        ("string1", 1)
        ("string2", 2)
        ("string3", 3)
        ;
```

Which prints **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1440afe1ead792b0)</kbd>**

```
Parsed: (42;3;more names or stuff;6.7)
```

Finally, you might use `raw[]` instead to "transduce" the input sequence, for example combined with `qi::no_space[]`: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0238aca5ab8e3e37)</kbd>**

```
        >>  raw[no_case[symbol_]] >> ','
```

Prints

```
Parsed: (42;sTrInG3;more names or stuff;6.7)
```

Comment: I was about to post a similar answer, but you beat me.  +1

Comment: @HenriMenke Cheers. Happens all the time. Welcome to post if you feel that several angles on the same thing add value. It's not a zero-sum game (is it a game anyways?) :)

Answer (score 3):

After Seth encouraged me in the comments to post my answer as well, here it is.  As expected, it is very similar with the difference that I dynamically construct the symbols from a `std::array` passed to the grammar.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

struct employee {
    int age;
    std::string surname;
    std::string forename;
    double salary;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(employee, age, surname, forename, salary)

namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename Iterator, std::size_t N>
struct employee_parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, employee(), ascii::space_type> {
    employee_parser(std::array<std::string, N> const &match_list)
        : employee_parser::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;

        for (auto match : match_list) {
            employees.add(match, match);
        }

        quoted_string %= lexeme['"' >> +(char_ - '"') >> '"'];

        start %=
            lit("employee")
            >> '{'
            >>  int_ >> ','
            >>  quoted_string >> ','
            >>  employees >> ','
            >>  double_
            >>  '}'
            ;
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type> quoted_string;
    qi::rule<Iterator, employee(), ascii::space_type> start;
    qi::symbols<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type,
                std::string> employees;
};

template <typename Iterator, std::size_t N>
employee parse(Iterator first, Iterator last,
               std::array<std::string, N> const &match_list) {
    employee_parser<Iterator, N> const grammar(match_list);
    employee e;
    bool r = qi::phrase_parse(first, last, grammar, ascii::space, e);

    if (!r || first != last) {
        std::cerr << "Parsing failed at " + std::string(first, last) + "\n";
    }

    return e;
}

int main() {
    employee e;
    std::array<std::string, 4> match_list = {"Homer", "Marge", "Lisa", "Bart"};

    std::string homer = "employee { 38, \"Simpson\", Homer, 3.0 }";
    e = parse(homer.begin(), homer.end(), match_list);
    std::cout << "employee { " << e.age << ", " << e.surname << ", "
              << e.forename << ", " << e.salary << " }\n";

    // Fails parsing because Hans Mole is not in the list
    std::string mole = "employee { 100, \"Mole\", Hans, 0.0 }";
    e = parse(mole.begin(), mole.end(), match_list);
    std::cout << "employee { " << e.age << ", " << e.surname << ", "
              << e.forename << ", " << e.salary << " }\n";
}
```

```
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++11 test.cpp
$ ./a.out 
employee { 38, Simpson, Homer, 3 }
Parsing failed at employee { 100, "Mole", Hans, 0.0 }
employee { 100, Mole, , 0 }
```

---

Here is also a reference for Homer's salary being 3.0: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIEWgwRrY9s